# Specify DataType using read_table() in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am loading a text file into pandas, and have a field that contains year.  I want to make sure that this field is a string when pulled into the dataframe.

I can only seem to get this to work if I specify the exact length of the string using the code below:
df = pd.read_table('myfile.tsv', dtype={'year':'S4'})

Is there a way to do this without specifying length?  I will need to perform this action on different columns that vary in length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe we enabled in 0.12

you can pass `str`,`np.str_`,`object` in place of an `S4`
which all convert to `object` dtype in any event

or after you read it in

`df['year'].astype(object)`

Comment: yep that was the chnge (to enable u to pass str) as a dtype (or S4) if u really wanted - both r converted to object

Comment: Am am using 11.0. Using str and np.str doesn't seem to work. But using 'object' does -> pd.read_table('myfile.tsv', dtype={'year':object}).